# Python: How to access tuple values inside a dictionary of a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dict of dict setup as follows:

```
from collections import namedtuple

Point = namedtuple('Point', 'r w')
mydict= {
    'user1': {'item1': Point(2.5,0.1),'item2': Point(3.5,0.6)},
    'user2': {'item1': Point(3.0,0.3), 'item3': Point(3.5,0.8)},
    'user3': {'item1': Point(2.0,0.4),'item3': Point(0.5,0.1), 'item4': Point(1.5,0.7)}
}
```

I would like to find an efficient way of getting the average of the values in Point. i.e. I want to get the average of the r point value (point.r) for 'item3' which is (3.5+0.5)/2

Thanks,

Comment: Keep in mind, you don't need backslashes to continue lines if you have unbalanced delimiters like { and }.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
r_vals = [u['item3'].r for u in mydict.itervalues() if 'item3' in u]
if r_vals:
   r_avg = sum(r_vals)/len(r_vals)
else:
   r_avg = 0   # ???
```